# When should I use Layaway vs. saving up for an item?

Tags: united-states, wire-transfer, down-payment

I'm going to buy a watch for `$100,000`. The seller says that I can deposit `$30,000` by wire-transfer, and then pay the whole thing off in `6 months`, and after it is fully paid, I will get the watch. I can afford this, but why should I risk paying him this money, when I can just save this on my own without paying him a dime? Are there any advantages to layaway?

If It helps understand why I would spend that much on a watch here's a similar one: http://www.jomashop.com/audemars-piguet-watch-26322or-zz-1222or-01.html?utm_source=googleproduct&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=googleproductsearch&pt_source=googleads&pt_medium=cpc&pt_campaign=(ROI)+Shopping+-+Non-Sale+Watches+$10000+-+25000&gclid=CK2zvua_oNQCFRBMDQodl1EMsQ

Comment: You would do that to guarantee the price of the item you're buying, and/or the item's availability.

Comment: @quid Good point, but layaway forces you to go first, which increases your chances of being scammed.

Comment: sure but you asked why would anyone use layaway, you would use lay away to set the price of the item and guarantee it's availability even though you can't pay completely today.

Comment: When you say $, I hope you mean pesos, rubles, lire or other penny currency.  That amount in anglo-nation dollars is worth committing high fraud over, and you should be intensely on guard. The fact that wire transfer is involved suggests this is not an in-person deal with a blue-chip retailer.

Comment: @Harper $100,000 USD

Comment: Would you make an unsecured $100,000 loan to the seller?  Because that is what it is when you layaway.

Comment: ...unsecured interest free loan.

Comment: You are making a huge mistake investing any amount like that in a stupid watch. Get a Timex or Casio for 15 USD at Target or Wallmart. And if you carry around a cell phone like most folks these days there is no need for a watch at all. Instead keep your cash and "lay it away" in a savings account or realistic investment.

Comment: It's not for an investment it's for style here's the watch (not the seller): http://www.jomashop.com/audemars-piguet-watch-26322or-zz-1222or-01.html?utm_source=googleproduct&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=googleproductsearch&pt_source=googleads&pt_medium=cpc&pt_campaign=(ROI)+Shopping+-+Non-Sale+Watches+$10000+-+25000&gclid=CK2zvua_oNQCFRBMDQodl1EMsQ

Comment: Good point Harper I might just goto the jewelry shop since its more safe, even through its all the way in new york

Comment: @MichaelKaras No, I would say go *serious* vintage. *Serious* like classy.  Impeccable antique finds, stuff that nobody else can even get because it's too rare. Those are cheap.   Dropping fat stax on Rodeo Drive just says trying to make up for a lack of style with raw cash.  Who would the girl rather go home with, the guy with the generic 2017 Ferrari or the guy in the flawlessly restored Citroen DS21?

Comment: If you can afford to spend $100,000 on a watch, you can afford to do things in a way that doesn't require you to wire $30,000 into the void.

Comment: Am I the only one that finds it odd that someone who can afford a $100K watch is asking for advice about layaway plans on stackexchange?

Comment: @quid "guarantee the price of the item you're buying, and/or the item's availability."  **That** is the answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Are there any advantages to layaway?

There are two main advantages.

First, when you pay the initial deposit the seller reserves the item for you at a given price. This is helpful with unique products, like a high-end custom-made watch. If there is only one of those watches in the entire world, then it's nice to know that the seller won't sell it to anyone else while you're getting together the remaining funds and the price you're paying is locked in.

Second, layaway agreements often allow for a payment plan. This is helpful for people who have a hard time saving up money. For many, it's easier to make smaller monthly payments than a large one-time payment.

Of course the cost of layaway is that you're $30,000 short for up to 6 months. This money could be generating a significant amount of interest during a half-year period. You'll need to make sure that reserving the item and locking in the price are worth this cost.

Comment: By, I can afford this I mean I can afford the layaway

Comment: @NoahCristino Thanks for the clarification. I've edited my response

Comment: "For many, it's easier to make smaller monthly payments than a large one-time payment." - This cuts both ways... if I was the OP, after saving $100,000 and seeing how much work that took, I would realise there were better things to spend money on than a $100,000 watch. With the layaway, I'd be stuck with the watch.

Comment: Good point user20574 I don't want to be stuck into buying it